# Return notification flash data with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, notifications, response

Currently I'm returning errors as following:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator); // <--
}
```

And display them in the template:

```
{{ isset($errors) ? $errors->first() : '' }}
```

What I would like to achieve is to return a notification which can be a 'info', 'success' or 'error' notice. Something like this:

```
return Redirect::to('login')->with('notification', 'error', $validator); //Error message
return Redirect::to('login')->with('notification', 'success', 'Logged in!'); //Success message
```

And then display them, something like this:

```
{{ isset('$notification') ? '<div class="notification ' . $notification[1] . '">$notification[2]</div>' : '' }}
```

Something like this should be possible, right?

Comment: You don't need to check `isset($errors)` - it's always defined in the view. However this is kind of special and other session variables can't be accessed this way (it's done in the view service provider), so you have to get them through `Session::get('success')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is of any help to you but this is what I've been doing.

In the controllers, we'll return the user to a page with a few different things.

For errors, we do it exactly like you do.

```
return Redirect::to('/whatever')->withErrors($validator);
```

And for successes, something similar.

```
return Redirect::to('/whatever')->with('success', "Hooray, things are awesome!");
```

However, in the view where the errors and notifications go, you'll just see this.

```
@include('global.notifications')
```

which contains the following. (you don't need to explicitly hand `$errors` to the view, its always there.)

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach($errors->all('<p>:message</p>') as $error)
            {{ $error }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif

@if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the best/easiest way to do it